# QR code detection

Tags: opencv, qr-code

I need an algorithm to detect FIPs in arbitrary images containing QR codes. I found a few algorithms for detecting QR codes but they dont seem to work if the image of the QR code is small and if it is taken from an angle. I would really appreciate any help in detecting such QR codes.

Answer (score 0):

manipulate the image beforehand. You could zoom in and apply a binarization with a proper threshold, because zooming in may leeds to a lower quality.

If your picture is taken from an angle, you could try to compensate it with a proper algorithm, or just prevent pictures to be taken from your app if the device is not horizontally or vertically aligned (if you are developing for a smart phone device), this removes some of the possible angles, but not all.

Comment: I am using a static camera and these QR codes are for selecting corresponding points during calibration process. So, zooming is not an option I have. So, I wanted some kind of algorithm just to detect the centers of the FIPs from a camera that is mounted on a wall.

Comment: by zooming I was talking about cropping the image and resizing it.
And for the algorithm I can only come up with this: http://www.gson.org/thesis/warping-thesis.pdf